# I can't compile anything with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, clang, codeblocks

I am running Code::Blocks version Code::Blocks 16.01 on Ubuntu 16.10 "Yakkety". The compiler I use is GCC 6.2.

I can't compile anything since I tried to switch my compiler to Clang 3.9.1.

When I try to re-build a project (named "Hello, World!" here) that already is built before, it fails. The build log is:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Hello, World! (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++-6 -Wall -g -O3 -std=c++1z  -c "/home/ndos/바탕화면/Hello, World!/Hello, World!.cpp" -o "obj/Debug/Hello, World!.o"
g++-6  -o "bin/Debug/Hello, World!" "obj/Debug/Hello, World!.o"   
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/Hello, World!.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

When I make a new project (named "Hello, World!" here) and try to build, it also fails. The build log is:

```
-------------- Build: Release in Hello, World! (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++-6 -Wall -O2 -O3 -std=c++1z  -c "/home/ndos/바탕화면/Hello, World!/Hello, World!.cpp" -o "obj/Release/Hello, World!.o"
g++-6  -o "bin/Release/Hello, World!" "obj/Release/Hello, World!.o"  -s  
g++-6: error: obj/Release/Hello, World!.o: No such file or directory
g++-6: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I have already tried reinstalling Code::Blocks, reinstalling GCC, purging Clang, switching the compiler back to GCC, but none of them worked.

Comment: You may answer your own question if you have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This problem occured because the path contained non-ASCII characters; I solved it. Furthermore, I changed the default language from Korean to English.